# Como transportar informações entre Activities

Tags: android-activity

Eu sou iniciante em Android e estou com o seguinte problema. Eu tenho uma tela (Activity) onde é informado a condição de pagamento e a tipo de pagamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no campo de condição de pagamento é aberto outra tela com uma lista das condições de pagamento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico em um item da lista eu seleciono um item dessa lista volta para tela anterior onde carrega os valores do item selecionado como pode ser observado na primeira imagem. Porém quando eu clico no campo tipo de pagamento realiza o mesmo processo abre uma nova tela com a lista dos tipos de pagamento e ao clicar em um item da lista volta para a tela anterior com as informações do tipo de pagamento. Só que ao voltar para a tela carrega as informações do tipo de pagamento, porém limpa as informações antes carregadas da forma de pagamento.

- Como devo trata para que a informação preenchida anteriormente não seja perdida?

Comment: Por favor faça um crop dessas imagens, deixe somente a parte relevante.

Comment: Coloque o código que você está usando para voltar à tela anterior e para passar esses dados entre as telas.

Comment: Dá uma lida sobre manter estados de tela. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=pt-br